# How do I use XUnit `InlineData` so that I can insert multiple test data for MultipartFormDataContent?

Tags: c#, xunit

I have this working Xunit code.

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task When_DocumentTypeInvalidFileType_Then_ShouldFail()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var filePath = @"D:\Files\test.pdf";

            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {                
                    form.Add(new StringContent(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), "Id");

                    var file = new StreamContent(stream);

                    file.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
                    form.Add(file, "File", Path.GetFileName(filePath));

                    // Act                
                    var response = await client.PostAsync("/ABC/Document", form);

                    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    _output.WriteLine("response: {0}", responseString);

                    HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
                    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, statusCode);

                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseMessage>(responseString);
                    Assert.Equal("Invalid file type.", result.file[0]);
                }
            }
        }
```

But the above only test for one scenario. How do I use XUnit `InlineData` so that I can insert multiple test data for `MultipartFormDataContent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, @"D:\Files\test.pdf")]
[InlineData(MediaTypeNames.Application.Xml, @"D:\Files\test.xml")]
// else files what you need
public async Task When_DocumentTypeInvalidFileType_Then_ShouldFail(string contentType, string filePath)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                form.Add(new StringContent(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), "Id");

                var file = new StreamContent(stream);

                file.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
                form.Add(file, "File", Path.GetFileName(filePath));

                // Act                
                var response = await client.PostAsync("/ABC/Document", form);

                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                _output.WriteLine("response: {0}", responseString);

                HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
                Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, statusCode);

                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseMessage>(responseString);
                Assert.Equal("Invalid file type.", result.file[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestGenerator.GetTestData), MemberType = typeof(TestGenerator))]
public async Task When_DocumentTypeInvalidFileType_Then_ShouldFail(string contentType, string filePath)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                form.Add(new StringContent(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), "Id");

                var file = new StreamContent(stream);

                file.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
                form.Add(file, "File", Path.GetFileName(filePath));

                // Act                
                var response = await client.PostAsync("/ABC/Document", form);

                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                _output.WriteLine("response: {0}", responseString);

                HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
                Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, statusCode);

                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseMessage>(responseString);
                Assert.Equal("Invalid file type.", result.file[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}

class TestGenerator
{
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetTestData() => new List<object[]>
    {
        new object[] { MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, @"D:\Files\test.pdf" },
        new object[] { MediaTypeNames.Application.Xml, @"D:\Files\test.xml" }
    };
}
```